# Why Class instance overwrites another instance

Tags: c#, class, console-application, instance, overwrite

I've an issue to ask you guys.

**I have a class shown below:**

```
public class Node
        {
            public int Kova1;               // Kova 1
            public int Kova2;               // Kova 2
            public int Kova3;               // Kova 3

            public int ActionNo;            // Yapılan İşlem

            public Node(int kova1, int kova2, int kova3, int actionNumber)
            {
                Kova1 = kova1;
                Kova2 = kova2;
                Kova3 = kova3;
                ActionNo = actionNumber;
            }

            public Node(int kova1, int kova2, int kova3)
            {
                Kova1 = kova1;
                Kova2 = kova2;
                Kova3 = kova3;
            }

            public Node()
            {
            }

            public Node AnneNode;
        }
```

**And these functions:**

```
public void CocukNodeOlustur(LinkedList<Node> Acik, LinkedList<Node> Kapali, Node temp)
{
    Node cocukState;

    Node temp2 = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cocukState = YeniStateOlustur(temp, i);

        if ((ActionKontrol(cocukState)) && (GoalBulundu(Acik, Kapali, cocukState)) &&
        ((cocukState.Kova1 != temp2.Kova1) && (cocukState.Kova2 != temp2.Kova2) && (cocukState.Kova3 != temp2.Kova3)))
        {
            cocukState.AnneNode = temp;
            Acik.AddFirst(temp);
        }
    }
}

public Node YeniStateOlustur(Node s, int j)
{
    int tempKova1, tempKova2, tempKova3;

    Node yeniCocuk = new Node();

    yeniCocuk = s;
    yeniCocuk.ActionNo = j;

    // Gelen numaraya göre uygulanan işlemin seçimi yapılıyor.
    switch (j)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                yeniCocuk.Kova1 += (3 - yeniCocuk.Kova1);
                yeniCocuk.Kova2 += 0;
                yeniCocuk.Kova3 += 0;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            {
                yeniCocuk.Kova1 += 0;
                yeniCocuk.Kova2 += (5 - yeniCocuk.Kova2);
                yeniCocuk.Kova3 += 0;
            }
            break;
    }

    return yeniCocuk;
}
```

**In the main function**

```
            Node temp = new Node();

            while (!(Acik.Count == 0))
            {
                p.CocukNodeOlustur(Acik, Kapali, temp);
                Kapali.AddLast(temp);
            }
```

So When I debug my program, I see that Whenever the code jumps to the **YeniStateOlustur**() function, all the Node instance's in program is affected by the changes in **YeniStateOlustur**(). **It seems the instance in the function overwrite all instances of Node class**.

I don't understand why it happens?

How can I overcome this?

My best regards and sory for the long post.

Comment: "My best regards and sory for the long post" - why didn't you make it shorter then? You've given *way* more code than you needed to - a short but *complete* example would have been much easier to work with.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sory I could'nt make it easier :/

Comment: I'm sure you *could* have made it simpler... I suspect you just haven't tried very much. Do you think you *really* need all of that code to demonstrate the problem? Have you tried removing extraneous bits, until it does *nothing* but show the confusing behaviour? You've presented us with about 250 lines of code with no indication of what it's meant to achieve, and only a pretty vague description of what actually happens.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to edit now. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, that's *somewhat* better - now I notice you're not using `YapilanAction`, `BaslangicNode` or `SonucNode`, although you appear to be using `Acik`, `p` and `Kapali` which aren't declared. Again, a single short but complete program (not three snippets) would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *all of the nodes are the same instance*.  Your sample code includes "new Node()" only twice, and in the second case (inside the method `YeniStateOlustur`), the new instance is immediately discarded.  That function therefore returns the same node that was passed to it:

```
public Node YeniStateOlustur(Node s, int j)  
{  
    int tempKova1, tempKova2, tempKova3;  

    Node yeniCocuk = new Node();  

    yeniCocuk = s;  

    //...

    return yeniCocuk;    
}
```

In the method `CocukNodeOlustur`, all node variables point to the same Node:

```
public void CocukNodeOlustur(LinkedList<Node> Acik, LinkedList<Node> Kapali, Node temp) 
{ 
    // here, temp == temp
    Node cocukState;
    // now, temp == temp and cocukState is uninitialized.
    Node temp2 = temp; 
    // now, temp == temp, temp2 == temp, and cocukState is uninitialized.

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
    { 
        cocukState = YeniStateOlustur(temp, i); 
        // now, temp == temp, temp2 == temp, and cocukState == temp

        if ((ActionKontrol(cocukState)) && (GoalBulundu(Acik, Kapali, cocukState)) && 
        ((cocukState.Kova1 != temp2.Kova1) && (cocukState.Kova2 != temp2.Kova2) && (cocukState.Kova3 != temp2.Kova3))) 
        { 
            cocukState.AnneNode = temp; 
            Acik.AddFirst(temp); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Your code seems to assume that Node is a value type (struct), but it is obviously a reference type (class).  If you're unsure about the difference, you should take a step back and do some reading and experimentation.

A quick fix might be to change the declaration of Node to a struct, but I would recommend against that.  Programming with structs can be very tricky, and that would be especially true if your understanding of the differences between structs and classes is shaky.

Comment: so I should write Node cocukState = new Node(); ?

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim where would you write that?  How would it help?  As soon as you call `cocukState = YeniStateOlustur(temp, i);`, cocukState will point to temp.  It does not matter what it pointed to before that call, or whether it was initialized or uninitialized.

Comment: if I use struct type, I can't write "public Node AnneNode". it's not permitted. I'm really confused.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim right, because structs cannot recursively contain their own type.  Just stick with the class.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim I'm not sure I've made myself understood -- is my answer clear enough?